# Autofac - Register all Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, autofac

Is there a way to ask Autofac to automatically register all Windows Forms in my assembly? This feature would most likely be similar to the Autofac MVC support's ability to register all controllers?

Right now, I do:

```
foreach (var type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypesSafely().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form))))
    builder.RegisterType(type);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a built in method to add all Win Forms. But you can do something like this.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form)));
```

Comment: Perfect. I added an extra close parenthesis for you though. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a short and sweet way of doing it:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .AssignableTo<Form>();
```