# Autofac Container in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am new to IoC, especially with Autofac. Some days I was confused with IoC in the Windows Application Form. The obstacle is how to display (like: Show, ShowDialog) the form that has been registered. While IContainer can only be accessed locally (private) Program.cs.

Actually, can IoC be used in the Windows Application Form? I gave a sample code that confused me.

```cs
#
# Demo.Core Project
#

namespace Demo.Core.Repository
{
    public interface IBaseRepository<T>
    {
        DbConnection CreateConnection();
        IEnumerable<T> Get(IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null);
    }

    public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public DbConnection CreateConnection()
        {
            return new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;User ID=sa;Password=Default!3;Initial Catalog=DemoIoC;");
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Get(IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null)
        {
            using (var connection = CreateConnection())
                return connection.GetAll<T>(transaction, commandTimeout);
        }
    }

    public interface IUserRepository : IBaseRepository<User> { }
    public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User>, IUserRepository { }
}

namespace Demo.Core.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
#
# Demo.Winform Project
#

using Demo.Core.Models;
using Demo.Core.Repository;

namespace Demo.Winform
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static IContainer Container;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Container = Configure();

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }

        static IContainer Configure()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>();
            builder.RegisterType<UserManagerForm>();

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }


    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            button1.Click += new EventHandler(delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                using (var container = *** HOW TO GET CONTAINER ? ***)
                {
                    Form manager = container.Resolve<UserManagerForm>();
                    manager.ShowDialog();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public partial class UserManagerForm : Form
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository repository;
        public UserForm(IUserRepository repository) : this()
        {
            this.repository = repository;
        }

        public UserForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnShown(e);

            listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            listBox1.DataSource = repository.Get();
        }
    }
}
```

I have read how to register form types in containers: [Autofac - Register all Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446726/autofac-register-all-windows-forms). But the question is, how do I resolve the form that was registered and show form?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just reference it via `Program.Container`?

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't even use the container directly. Providing the container reference to the components is like introducing an all-mighty service locator. It kind of breaks the whole purpose of the IoC/DI concept.

Comment: @stuartd It can, but what if I access it in another project? In case I need IUserRepository in form on another project.

Comment: @dymanoid: I could just add a static class and save the Container as a property `public static IContainer Container { get; set; }`. But it seems like it's not recommended. What is the solution for the code above?

Comment: As Windows Forms has zero support for IoC, I'm wondering why you're using it anyway? You have no option except to use the [service locator anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), so what is it going to achieve for you?

Comment: Starting from the web (asp), I tried the implementation of IoC on windows form. But apparently, zero support. Thank you @stuartd, I will use the service locator anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me ,You just get the service from the container \

```
static class Program
{
    public static IContainer Container;
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Container = Configure();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1(Container.Resolve<IWindowsFormsApp3Client>()));

    }
    static Autofac.IContainer Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register<IWindowsFormsApp3Client>(ctor => new WindowsFormsApp3Client(new Uri("https://localhost:44381"), new CustomLoginCredentials()))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
      //  builder.RegisterType<WindowsFormsApp3Client>().As<IWindowsFormsApp3Client>();
        builder.RegisterType<Form1>();

     
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
public class CustomLoginCredentials : ServiceClientCredentials
{
    private string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       // AuthenticationToken = Extensions.GetAppsettingsToken()?.AccessToken;
        if (AuthenticationToken != null)
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthenticationToken);
        }
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        await base.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    }
}
```